Cross-correlation SD
Is there a known best practice or mathematically well defined way of computing a continuous SD for cross correlation?  Or do you just computer the SD at each sample point?  I'm curious because then for purposes of significance like WHEN the signal becomes significantly different or stops being significantly different you'd need to apply multiple test-correction and I'm just wondering how that plays out in continuous time?
Here is a simulation in numpy to plot it:
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.signal import correlate

# Generate synthetic data for visualization
np.random.seed(0)
signal_1 = np.sin(np.linspace(0, 10, 1000)) + 0.1 * np.random.normal(size=1000)
signal_2 = np.sin(np.linspace(0, 10, 1000) + np.pi / 4) + 0.1 * np.random.normal(size=1000)

# Compute cross-correlation
cross_corr = correlate(signal_1, signal_2, mode='full')
lags = np.arange(-len(signal_1) + 1, len(signal_2))

# Compute standard deviation over 1000 bootstrap samples
bootstrap_samples = 1000
sample_sd = np.zeros(len(cross_corr))

for i in range(bootstrap_samples):
    # Generate random samples for bootstrap
    sampled_signal_1 = signal_1 + np.random.normal(scale=0.1, size=len(signal_1))
    sampled_signal_2 = signal_2 + np.random.normal(scale=0.1, size=len(signal_2))
    sampled_corr = correlate(sampled_signal_1, sampled_signal_2, mode='full')
    sample_sd += (sampled_corr - cross_corr) ** 2

sample_sd = np.sqrt(sample_sd / bootstrap_samples)

# Plotting cross-correlation with SD
plt.figure(figsize=(10, 6))
plt.plot(lags, cross_corr, label='Cross-correlation')
plt.fill_between(lags, cross_corr - sample_sd, cross_corr + sample_sd, color='gray', alpha=0.3, label='SD over 1000 samples')
plt.xlabel('Lags')
plt.ylabel('Cross-correlation')
plt.title('Cross-correlation with Standard Deviation')
plt.legend()
plt.grid()
plt.show()

Note a question was posted about this on another slack but it was never answer and badly written: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78669859/how-to-calculate-the-confidence-intervals-for-a-time-lagged-cross-correlation
